# How can I pattern match on Ellipsis or NotImplemented

Tags: python, pattern-matching

How can I match `...` (`Ellipsis`) and `NotImplemented` in Python's pattern? The naive attempt of

```
import random
x = random.choice([..., NotImplemented])

match x:
    case NotImplemented:
        print("1")
    case ...:
        print("2")
```

fails in two ways:

- `...` is a syntax error
- `NotImplemented` is treated as an identifier not a constant, so matches everything!

Using `Ellipsis` instead of `...` runs into the same problem as `NotImplemented`, in that it matches everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing these names via `.` notation on the [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) means that `match` treats them as constants:

```
import builtins

match x:
    case builtins.NotImplemented:
        print("1")
    case builtins.Ellipsis:
        print("2")
```

---

Another approach is to use the `Type()` notation of pattern matching, and match on the types of these constants instead of the values:

```
NotImplementedType = type(NotImplemented)
EllipsisType = type(Ellipsis)

match x:
    case NotImplementedType():
        print("1")
    case EllipsisType():
        print("2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Eric's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73204168/8582902), we can also hold the value in a temporary variable and then use `if` on it, as follows:

```
import random
x = random.choice([..., NotImplemented])

match x:
    case val if val is NotImplemented:
        print("1")
    case val if val is ...:
        print("2")
```

The advantage with this approach is that there is no preparation or imports needed.